# How to add Json file with image byte array in postman webAPI

Tags: c#, json, image, asp.net-core, postman

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see I want to add directly image file to the sql server by getting id, carId, uploadDate as Json and imagePath as file byte array.
How can I do that what should I change ?

Comment: declare `ImagePath` as `IFormFile `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#no-source-for-a-model-property) can not handle byte arrays that would be set to `null`.

As @viveknuna mentioned, if possible, you can try to use `IFormFile` to process or save the uploaded file.

Besides, if you really want to bind selected file to byte arrays, you can try to implement and use a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-model-binder-sample), like below.

```
public class ImageToByteArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...

            

        if (bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["ImagePath"]?.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileBytes = new byte[bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["ImagePath"].Length];

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["ImagePath"].CopyTo(ms);
                fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(fileBytes);
        }


            
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Apply the ModelBinder attribute to model property

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ImageToByteArrayModelBinder))]
public byte[] ImagePath { get; set; }
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: I changed my controller a bit [HttpPost("add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] CarImage carImage, IFormFile imageFile) so I get FormFile then I convert it to byte array It works fine now thank you public static async Task<byte[]> ConvertFormFileToByteArray(IFormFile formFile)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                byte[] imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return imageBytes;
            }
        }